# Invalid DB Instance class: db.t2.micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Why can I not create a database of size `db.t2.micro` in CloudFormation?
Here is my template:

```
Resources:
  Database:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties: 
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      AllowMajorVersionUpgrade: No
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      DBName: myDB
      DeletionProtection: no
      Engine: mysql
      MasterUsername: admin
      MasterUserPassword: superSecret
      MultiAZ: no
      PubliclyAccessible: yes
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SG
```

And the error that I am getting is:

```
Invalid DB Instance class: db.t2.micro (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: ????; Proxy: null)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The region is `eu-north-1` but it also doesn't work in `eu-west-2`.

Comment: Could be an issue of trying to use a newer version of mysql with an old instance class (t2). Does db.t3.micro work?

Comment: Weirdly, it did work in `eu-west-2` when I tried it again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following AWS CLI command to check whether a DB instance class is orderable in a particular AWS region:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql --db-instance-class db.t2.micro --region eu-north-1
```

In this case, it returns

```
{
    "OrderableDBInstanceOptions": []
}
```

This means that the `db.t2.micro` is not orderable in `eu-north-1`.